# effect on SEO on changing the title of page dynamically using javascript

Tags: seo

Where would be the location of webpage, (on server or client) when a search-bot crawls it.

And another question is if I dynamically change the title and meta-keyword of a webpage, how will it affect the search engines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crawler is pretty much like any other **basic** client :

- it'll request the page from your server,
- download it,
- and *look* at it localy

This is exactly like when you're requesting that same page from your server using firefox, and reading it in firefox *(except "firefox" is replaced by "crawler")*

If you dynamically change something :

- If that modification is done server-side, the page that's downloaded by the crawler will contain this modification.
- If the modification is done client-side *(Javascript, typically -- like you're currently doing)*, chances are high the crawler won't see them : **crawlers don't typically really interpret Javascript**.

Comment: and how does a crawler request a page then? for example:- `http://someurl.com?page=21` . Does it happen the same time we request it?

Comment: When you have 3 users requesting a page using firefox/ie/chrome/whatever, and a crawler, the crawler will be just like a fourth user -- *using a more basic browser*

Comment: 2017 update: Google and most other crawlers do execute javascript nowadays. See how Google sees your page from here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en